# Audio Unit recording: increased volume of buffers

Tags: ios, xcode, core-audio, audiounit

I am building an audio recording app for iPhone in which I use remote audio units. After performing some audio analysis on incoming buffers I write the buffers to disk using:

ExtAudioFileWriteAsync

However, the problem I have is that the recorded buffers are quieter than I would like.

I would like to increase the volume of the buffers by manually multiplying them by a volume factor just prior to writing to disk. Can anyone please explain to me the best way to do this?

(For various reasons, a manual adjustment at the final stage is more attractive than changing any of the audio unit properties, which otherwise work well for my application.)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you know exactly how much gain you want?  Do you know this amount of gain will not cause clipping?  What is the format of your data? (linear 16-bit or ?). What quality level of gain adjustment are you looking for?

Comment: The buffer is originally linear 16-bit, which i convert to float for the audio analysis phase. However, in the end I write the original, uncoverted AudioBufferList as this was the approach that worked. However, I think I now need to return an adjusted version of the buffer back into an AudioBufferList so it can be written with that function. At what level does clipping occur? Is there such thing as a better quality of gain adjustment than simple mutiplication? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Accelerate.framework` to do this quickly and easily.  Since you are using AudioUnits I assume you have deinterleaved float buffers so something like this should work:

```
float desiredGain = 1.06f; // or whatever linear gain you'd like
AudioBufferList *ioData; // audio from somewhere
for(UInt32 bufferIndex = 0; bufferIndex < ioData->mNumberBuffers; ++bufferIndex) {
  float *rawBuffer = (float *)ioData->mBuffers[bufferIndex].mData;
  vDSP_Length frameCount = ioData->mBuffers[bufferIndex].mDataByteSize / sizeof(float); // if you don't have it already
  vDSP_vsmul(rawBuffer, 1, &desiredGain, rawBuffer, 1, frameCount);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much - vDSP_vsmul appears to be the function I need. However, I am now struggling to get the adjusted buffer (currently floats) back into an AudioBufferList so that it can be written with ExtAudioFileWriteAsync. Any possibility you could explain that to me... and then you will officially be my hero!

Comment: I am getting an error on the line float * rawBuffer = ..... : Cannot initialize a variable of type 'float *' with an Ivalue of type 'void *'. Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to cast `mData` to the correct type.  I wrote the code in Chrome so I hadn't compiled it to check- I've added the typecast.

Comment: Hero status is now official! Thanks buddy!

Comment: The recording is now louder but is horribly distorted :( Any ideas?

Comment: The audio is probably clipping.  Are you doing anything with the samples after the gain application?

Comment: I mean, it is horrendously distorted, even when I enter a value such of 0.0 or 1.0 for gain. Nothing is done with the samples after gain application... and i've reduced the code to:

Comment: float desiredGain = 0.0f; 
float *rawBuffer = (float *)THIS->bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData;
vDSP_vsmul(rawBuffer, 1, &desiredGain, rawBuffer, 1, inNumberFrames); (as I only use buffer 0)

Answer (score 0):

You might be over thinking this problem. :-) You just need to loop over the values in your buffer and multiply each one by the desired gain factor.

Comment: If only Core Audio were so easy!

Comment: hi what about particular frequency gain?